# Having Problems with override the toString

Tags: java, syntax, overriding

The main problem I am having is the override the `toString()` and what exactly to put. If anyone can help that would be great!

```
// Circle inherits from GeometricObject and uses Drawable

public class Circle extends GeometricObject {
    private double radius;

    /**Default constructor*/
    public Circle() {
        this(1.0);
    }

    /**Overloaded constructor - construct a circle with a specified radius*/
    public Circle(double radius) {
        //call the local overloaded constructor and pass it the following: radius, "white", false
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    /**Overloaded constructor - construct a circle with specified radius, filled, and color*/
    public Circle(double radius, String color, boolean filled) {
        //call the GeometricObject's constructor and pass it color and filled
        this.radius = radius;
        setColor(color);
        setFilled(filled);
    }

    /**Return radius*/
    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    /**Set a new radius*/
    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    /**Implement the getArea method defined in GeometricObject*/
    public double getArea() {
        return radius*radius*Math.PI;
    }

    /**Implement the getPerimeter method defined in GeometricObject*/
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2*radius*Math.PI;
    }

    /**Override the equals() method defined in the Object class*/
    public boolean equals(Circle circle) {
        return this.radius == circle.getRadius();
    }
```

This is the main problem I have with the code. I need help with how the `toString()` method works and what to put in!

```
    /**Override the toString() method defined in the Object class*/
    //output for circle should be: "[Circle] radius = ; color = ;               filled = " : insert appropriate variables to the right of the equal sign
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return [Circle]
    }

    @Override
    public String Draw() {

    }

    @Override
    public String howToDraw() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as `C++`? I can't imagine you think they are the same language. (removed the tag)

Comment: I would use the IDE generated toString() method until you decide you want to customize it.

Comment: Okay so you have it correct just not what you are returning.. simply do something like.. `return "[Circle] radius = "+radius+" ; color = "+color+" ;";`   You will need a Color variable of some sort like `String color` and stuff for that to work..

Answer (score 2):

Where is the difficult?

```
return "[Circle] radius: "+this.radius+" ; color = "+this.color+";";
```

If color is private (in super class) you should use something like this:

```
return "[Circle] radius: "+this.radius+" ; color = "+getColor()+";";
```